# numpy meshgrid filter out points

Tags: python, numpy

I have a meshgrid in numpy. I make some calculations on the points. I want to filter out points that could not be calcutaled for some reason ( division by zero).

```
from numpy import arange, array
Xout = arange(-400, 400, 20)
Yout = arange(0, 400, 20)
Zout = arange(0, 400, 20)
Xout_3d, Yout_3d, Zout_3d = numpy.meshgrid(Xout,Yout,Zout)

#some calculations 
# for example 
b = z / ( y - x )
```

Comment: By filtering out, do you mean removing those in `Xout_3d, Yout_3d, Zout_3d`? If so, IIUC then, they can't stay as regular 3D arrays anymore. Or would it be okay to set those as NaNs or something?

Comment: I want to plot these points, so it is ok to set to NaN or even set to zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To perform `z / ( y - x )` using those `3D` mesh arrays, you can create a mask of the valid ones. Now, the valid ones would be the ones where any pair of combinations between `y` and `x` aren't identical. So, this mask would be of shape `(M,N)`, where `M` and `N` are the lengths of the `Y` and `X` axes respectively. To get such a mask to span across all combinations between `X` and `Y`, we could use [`NumPy's broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.4/user/basics.broadcasting.html). Thus, we would have such a mask like so -

```
mask = Yout[:,None] != Xout
```

Finally, and again using broadcasting to broadcast the mask along the first two axes of the`3D` arrays, we could perform such a division and choose between an invalid specifier and the actual division result using [`np.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html), like so -

```
invalid_spec = 0
out = np.where(mask[...,None],Zout_3d/(Yout_3d-Xout_3d),invalid_spec)
```

---

Alternatively, we can directly get to such an output using broadcasting and thus avoid using `meshgrid` and having those heavy `3D` arrays in workspace. The idea is to simultaneously populate the `3D` grids and perform the subtraction and division computations, both on the fly. So, the implementation would look something like this -

```
np.where(mask[...,None],Zout/(Yout[:,None,None] - Xout[:,None]),invalid_spec)
```

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer. I'm really sorry, but all there slices and ellipsises are beyond my comprehension. (((

Simply, I don't understand.

Comment: @microspace haha I don't blame you as these multidimensional concepts and broadcasting takes some time getting used to :)